# why same URL gives different results?

Tags: postman

Despite having the same url ,environment variables and inputs me and my colleague were getting different results(Json) in the postman. Here are the screen shots.[my colleague output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVmKq.png) 
[My output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fy5iD.png)

We have also changed workspaces (team to personal) and imported all the envs but still not getting the results.

Comment: check the section of preferred address.

Comment: Please follow => https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
so we can help.

Comment: Also add what you are trying to do

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that you Send no-cache header

> Send no-cache header (recommended): Sending a no-cache header makes
> sure you get the up-to-date response from your server

https://learning.postman.com/docs/getting-started/settings/